# Using networkx to create node labels from an array

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, networkx, data-science

I have some nodes that are being generated from a numpy adjacency matrix. I also have an array of labels for said nodes already where node 0 in the matrix corresponds to label 0 in the array. What is the easiest way to apply those labels to the nodes in the graph?

Comment: Can you give a quick sample of what exactly you want?  I can think of several questions you might be asking (is this about how to plot it with those nodes showing?  How to have the graph stored with those labels as attributes of the nodes?  How to have the graph stored with those labels *being* the nodes?)

Comment: I have the nodes drawn with numbers but I would like them each to have a label with a name. I have an array with the names in it where index X of the array corresponds to node X in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the labels while drawing but you must first convert the array into a dictionary where the key value is the node number and the value is the label. After whuch you can specify labels with the label argument like so:

```
nx.draw(G, labels=labelDict)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as of Feb 2023. Perhaps the functionality has changed?